# How to fetch documents using optimal range query with Mongo Expression in case of Couch DB?

Tags: php, couchdb

Suppose I have 200 documents in my database named "person" and I want to fetch documents from range 60 to 70 then how would I do in case of CouchDB, Right now I am using mongo expression and using 'skip' parameter for ranging queries but as soon as the skip size increases the query execution time also increases, is there any alternative to 'skip' parameter.?
In RDBMS we can fetch data easily using lower limit and upper limit but how would I do in case of CouchDB?

**Here is my query**

```
$getDocs = '{
    "selector": {
        "name": {"$ne": "null"}
    },
    "fields": ["_id", "_rev", "name", "email" ],
    "sort": [{"name": "asc" }],
    "limit": 10,
    "skip": '.$skip.'
}';
```

I am trying to do pagination with PHP and CouchDB using Mango Expression and showing 10 records per page.

[See the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJUXQ.png) as you click on the image you can see in my URL that I am on page 7 that means I need to fetch the documents between 61 to 70 and for that, I am using above query. In the above query, I am passing limit equals to 10 as I only need to show 10 documents per page and also I am using skip for skipping 60 documents since I am on page 7. So the problem came here is, as soon as the page number increases the number of documents to be skipped will also increase so the execution time of the query increases, suppose if I am on the page 1500 then on page 1500 I need to show documents between 15001 to 15010 and for that I need to skip 15000 documents and skipping such number of documents are taking time almost 7 secs which is quite high. So is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Please, define a bit your strategy for retrieving the docs. Are you using views? mango expressions?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you facing? Include your code/queries.

Comment: Asking people not to downvote your question is a sure way to get your question downvoted. Downvotes happen for a reason. Fix those reasons, rather than asking people to ignore the rules.

Comment: Alright now I have edited my question and explained in brief, can you help me out to resolve my problem now.

Answer (score 0):

For Mango queries, you have to use bookmarks. Full documentation can be found [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/find.html#pagination)

Preview:

> Mango queries support pagination via the bookmark field. Every _find response contains a bookmark - a token that CouchDB uses to determine where to resume from when subsequent queries are made. To get the next set of query results, add the bookmark that was received in the previous response to your next request. Remember to keep the selector the same, otherwise you will receive unexpected results. To paginate backwards, you can use a previous bookmark to return the previous set of results.
>
> Note that the presence of a bookmark doesn’t guarantee that there are more results. You can to test whether you have reached the end of the result set by comparing the number of results returned with the page size requested - if results returned < limit, there are no more.